# 3D Surface Plot Issue with colourbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface, colorbar

I am trying to plot values of the charge density of a crystal over the x=y plane. I have been able to plot a contour map of the charge density, and a wireframe (below)

[image: Wiremesh]

But it looks a bit messy. I would like to make a surface plot, so you can see where the atoms in the crystal are better (rather than being able to 'see through' the wire plot).

When I use the code (bottom of this description), I get the image below:

[image: Surface plot no colourbar]

Which obviously shows no colour variation. What have I done wrong here? Any help would be great!

Code below. Note the function "chgdens2" calculates the value of the charge density at various points in the plane.

```
fig = pyplot.figure()
x = numpy.linspace(-0.5*A,0.5*A,10) #Range of x vals 
z = numpy.linspace(-0.5*A,0.5*A,10) #Range of z vals
p = numpy.sqrt(2) * x
P, Z = numpy.meshgrid(p,z)
DENS = numpy.zeros((len(p), len(z)),dtype=numpy.float32)

for i in range (len(p)):
    for j in range(len(z)):
        DENS[i, j] = chgdens2(N,n,numpy.array([x[i],x[i],z[j]]),m)

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(P,Z,DENS, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, shade=True)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you add rstride=1, cstride=1 to your ax.plot_surface() function?